# Is there a way to throw exception if FileSystemWatcher does not fire after some time

Tags: .net

**Use case**

We have a service uploading a file in a folder and another service watching that folder. But we don't want to watch it eternally. So let's say we want to watch for 20 sec and then throw if the file is not there.

Comment: That's a design bug.  You would have to have these services communicate with each other, so the service would know when to start watching.  Using a named pipe for example.  Once you got that infrastructure in place, there is no longer any point in using FileSystemWatcher, the source service could simply post a message to indicate that the file is available.

Comment: You're right, but until it is changed, I wanted to know if there were any possibilities